# Distortion on TV display

Tags: display

I have an Intel Core i5 with an NVIDIA 920m gpu with a laptop display of 1600x900 and I’m trying to connect it to my TV using HDMI to play games, but I notice a bit of distortion, something like a line moving down the TV screen a bit every once in a while, I am currently running the two displays simultaneously. What do I do to stop the distortion?

Answer (score 0):

First, it would be useful if we could know the age of your TV, any damage, the model, the company that sold it, basic info, etc

But I would like to note that many cases of TV distortion come from cables, I had an HDMI that connected to my tv, and when I switched to it, it would cause MAJOR screen errors and glitches, even though it was a new cable, try unplugging all your cables and try again, if that doesn't work, try getting a new HDMI cable.

This can also erupt from power cables themselves, so try messing with your power cable, or buying a new one.

SECONDLY: THIS IS VERY IMPORTANT; Never place the power cable by your audio and video cables!!! Please make sure your power cable (Even if its wrapped/covered in plastic/rubber) IS NOT contacting with the video and audio cables, this isn't usually the case with newer televisions, but just try it anyways.

And one last thing: Make sure none of your outlets are shorted out!